# nmcli STATE unmanaged on eth0 device when the cable network is up and i can ping outside. Why is not labeled as connected?

Tags: ubuntu, nmcli

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, i'm testing to connect to network with both devices(interfaces) the eth0 and wlan0. I'm starting with the Wifi :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nmcli dev 
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION  
wlan0          wifi      connected  MY-NET 
eth0           ethernet  unmanaged  --          
lo             loopback  unmanaged  --          
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  unmanaged  --
```

All works great! Now i'm switching to the eth0 dev:

```
sudo nmcli con down MY-NET
sudo nmcli dev
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlan0          wifi      disconnected  --         
eth0           ethernet  unmanaged     --         
lo             loopback  unmanaged     --         
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  unmanaged     --
```

Now i connect the cable and i'm done with the eth0 connection:

```
ip addr show
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether dc:a6:32:22:b8:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.132/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 6500sec preferred_lft 6500sec
inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe22:b8a3/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ping nike.com
PING nike.com (99.86.167.33) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server-99-86-167-33.mxp64.r.cloudfront.net (99.86.167.33): icmp_seq=1 ttl=242 time=7.39 ms
64 bytes from server-99-86-167-33.mxp64.r.cloudfront.net (99.86.167.33): icmp_seq=2 ttl=242 time=7.24 ms
```

But every time i'm running the nmcli command on dev i cannot see the device eth0 active:

```
wlan0          wifi      disconnected  --         
eth0           ethernet  unmanaged     --         
lo             loopback  unmanaged     --         
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  unmanaged     --
```

So both the command on device and on connection are not showing the active link:

```
sudo nmcli dev set eth0 managed yes
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo nmcli dev
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlan0          wifi      disconnected  --         
eth0           ethernet  unmanaged     --         
lo             loopback  unmanaged     --         
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  unmanaged     --

sudo nmcli con show --active
>
```

Comment: Because eth0 is not managed by Network Manager, Network Manager ignores eth0's state, which includes eth0's connection state.

Comment: Thanks ... never though about!